# What does k mean in terms of sensitivity and specificity

Tags: terminology

I am learning a paper [Assessment of Deep Generative Models for High-Resolution Synthetic Retinal Image Generation of Age-Related Macular Degeneration](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6439721/), which uses an item "K" in the stats of sensitivity and specificity.

[image]

I [googled a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%20does%20k%20mean%20in%20terms%20of%20sensitivity%20and%20specificity&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=What%20does%20k%20mean%20in%20terms%20of%20sensitivity%20and%20specificity&aqs=chrome..69i57.359j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and didn't get a related hit. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not a 'k', its the letter Kappa, probably [Cohen's Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa), describing the statistic which typically measures the inter-rater agreement, but is sometimes also used for intra-rater agreement. That seems to be the case in this paper.

Comment: +1, because that is probably what it is supposed to be. However, I am puzzled. $\kappa$, as you write, measures the agreement between *two* raters in a multi-category classification task. But here, the paper reports separate $\kappa$s *for each rater*. This does not seem to make sense. The OP's best bet may be to contact the corresponding authors.

Comment: Good point about Kappa typically referring to inter-rater agreement! I briefly looked into the wiki article, and apparently Cohen's Kappa can also be used for intra-rater agreement, which is probably the case here. Edited the answer accordingly